# $this->Js->writeBuffer() writes invalid jquery code in cakephp 2.2.3

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm just upgrading some code from cakephp 1.1 to 2.2.3 and I'm stuck on the ajax bits. The forms are completely different but they've I've reworked them just fine.

When I view the source I get this from the echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); command

```
//<![CDATA[
$j(document).ready(function () {$("#AdlistingRegion").bind("click", function (event)     {$.ajax({async:true, dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#AdlistingDistrict").html(data);}, url:"\/adlistings\/getdistricts"});
return false;});
$("#AdlistingDistrict").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({async:true, dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#AdlistingSuburb").html(data);}, url:"\/adlistings\/getsuburbs"});
return false;});});
//]]>
```

however firebug tells me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

This appears to be a flaw in the library which doesn't seem plausible but I've got the JS helper in the controller and can't see which step I've missed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is included *before* this piece of code? Also, you seem to be using `$j` (a noConflict alias?) and then `$`. Why is that? — Try typing each of the following in your browser’s JS console and see what you get (after the page has fully loaded): `$`, `$j` and `jQuery`.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html recommends using the noconflict code. Because it's cakephp I haven't written the source code I've pasted.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the no-conflict code in general, but the second line doesn't use the no-conflict alias which likely causes your problem. However I'm not familiar with cakephp which is why I can't answer your question further.

Answer (score 0):

This is small hack but it works for me ;)

```
<?php echo str_replace('$(document).ready(function ()', 'jQuery(document).ready(function($)',  $this->Js->writeBuffer()); ?>
```

Read more about safe jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/